# How to delete object instances from Parse users account that matching a property

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

What I want to do is delete an instance of a `matchCenterItem` object under a user account, based on the "searchTerm" property of the instance. I've tried setting it up according to Parse documentation, but it's giving me an error stating: `Failed with: success/error was not called`.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("deleteFromMatchCenter", function(request, response) {

  var matchCenterItem = Parse.Object.extend("matchCenterItem");
  var query = new Parse.Query(matchCenterItem);

  query.containedIn('searchTerm', request.params.searchTerm);
  query.equalTo('parent', Parse.User.current())

  query.find().then(function(matchCenterItem) {
    return Parse.Object.destroyAll(matchCenterItem);
  }).then(function(success) {
    console.log("Match Center Item deleted, sweet!");
  }, function(error) {
    console.error("Error deleting related Match Center Items!");
  });


});
```

Comment: in the returned promise from your destroyAll call, call response.success() :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the error is correct, you need to call success or error on the response object passed in to the function, like:

```
Parse.Object.destroyAll(matchCenterItem).then(function() {
  response.success('ok');
}, function(err) {
  response.error(err);
}
```